# finding the minimum operations to get from x to y

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, minimum, operation

still struggling with recursion.
I have a code that's supposed to get me the least amount of operations in order to get from x to y.
only by multiplying by 2 or adding +1
e.g from 7 to 12... its 5 operations because you need +1 five times.
My code is not working correctly for me, and I can't figure out what I'm missing in order for it to be right.

```
public static int minOps(int x,int y)
{
    if (x >= y) return 0;
        int add = 1 + minOps(x + 1, y);
        int mul = 1 + minOps(x * 2, y);
    return Math.min(add, mul);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@arjunkhera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415634/3788176) has the right idea - return a "terrible" result when you've overshot, so you never select it - but needs to avoid the potential overflow when adding 1 to the result:

```
public static int minOps(int x,int y)
{
    // Return 1 less that MAX_VALUE, so adding 1 doesn't overflow.
    // You'll never get as far as here anyway, your stack will overflow long
    // before, so subtracting 1 makes no practical difference.
    if (x > y) return Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1;
    if (x >= y) return 0;

    int add = 1 + minOps(x + 1, y);
    int mul = 1 + minOps(x * 2, y);
    return Math.min(add, mul);
}
```

Alternatively, you could defer adding 1 until later:

```
    if (x > y) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    if (x >= y) return 0;

    int add = minOps(x + 1, y);
    int mul = minOps(x * 2, y);
    return 1 + Math.min(add, mul);
```

since at least one of `add` and `mul` will not be equal to `MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

You fail to take into account that overshooting is not legit and returning `0` is hence not correct. Simply change the following in your base case

```
if(x > y) return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
if(x == y) return 0;
```

Comment: Note that returning `Integer.MAX_VALUE` would lead to overflow to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` when you add 1 to the result, which would then be the min.

Comment: Also, try exploring DP. You can use memoization to improve your running time by remembering the values for which you have already calculated the result

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right. For cases with large values, the OP should make the check before calling the recursion. For other cases, I assume this should work fine

Comment: Ok, but adding that just gives me the MAX_VALUE everytime I run the program.

Comment: Well, no, it's not just "large values": what you're suggesting here will lead to the wrong answer when one of them overshoots, because the overshooting one is the minimum.

Comment: @AndyTurner any suggestions of a code that can do what I need?

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right. Completely missed that. The return +1 would always overflow.